Partition cannot be grown
I have increased the size of my EBS volume on my EC2 instance. Then I increased the size with growpart according to the documentation successfully.
However, the partition isn't actually grown. I am running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.
> lsblk  
...   
nvme1n1      259:4    0  450G  0 disk  
└─nvme1n1p1  259:5    0  450G  0 part /data

> df -h  
/dev/nvme1n1p1   344G  233G   96G  72% /data

> sudo growpart /dev/nvme1n1 1 -v
update-partition set to true
FLOCK: try exec open fd 9, on failure exec exits this program
FLOCK: /dev/nvme1n1: obtained exclusive lock
resizing 1 on /dev/nvme1n1 using resize_sfdisk_dos
943718400 sectors of 512. total size=483183820800 bytes
## sfdisk --unit=S --dump /dev/nvme1n1
label: dos
label-id: 0x49bd1793
device: /dev/nvme1n1
unit: sectors
sector-size: 512

/dev/nvme1n1p1 : start=        2048, size=   943716319, type=83
padding 33 sectors for gpt secondary header
max_end=943718367 tot=943718400 pt_end=943718367 pt_start=2048 pt_size=943716319
NOCHANGE: partition 1 is size 943716319. it cannot be grown
FLOCK: /dev/nvme1n1: releasing exclusive lock

How can I make the partition match the size of the disk?

After running growpart, you need to resize the filesystem with:
sudo resize2fs /dev/nvme1n1p1

This will expand the filesystem to use the full partition size.

I managed to skip step 3 in the docs. Thanks!
